# Can I propagate "yarn install" options through the bb (bobril build)

Tags: yarnpkg, bobril

I'm using Bobril and Bobril build and also use third party packages which have optional dependencies. In "yarn install" I would like to avoid to this kind of issues, through "yarn install --ignore-optional":

```
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "node_modules\\cpu-features: Command failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no such way.

I am thinking to make this new default.

BTW: Feel free to use Project Github issues to request features: https://github.com/bobril/bbcore/issues

Edit: It is now new default in 1.57+ version.